# ScrollView Positioning in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm new to programming in Xcode and I've got the following question:

How do I adjust the position of a view inside a NSScrollView?

[image: Screenshot]

I want my WKDDrawView to be positioned in the left upper corner and I just don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the center of window coordinate system is located in bottom left corner.

You should override the `isFlipped:` method in your `WKDDrawView` to return `YES`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my answer, I've fixed it.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks, but this doesn't help either.

Comment: Yes. It just changes the coordinate system inside WKDDrawView, but I want it to change the point the Custom View relates to inside the ScrollView.

Comment: You could always try subclassing the NSClipView ([scrollView contentView]) and make that flipped instead.

Comment: How exactly can I subclass NSClipView or actually how do I set my subclassed NSClipView to the ScrollView then?

Comment: I think the problem is in your layout.. Is your `WKDDrawView` is a `documentView` of `NSScrollView`? How did you put it to `NSScrollView`? You should do it like this: put your `WKDDrawView` on the window, select it and then go to Editor menu -> Embed In -> Scroll View. If you just drag it to your `NSScrollView` it places inside of `documentView` but doesn't set as `documentView`.